@ContextConfiguration Cant find class from another module
I have a big java Spring project with several modules. I decided to move some parts of the Spring tests from module server into a new module server-test, in order to split them logically and let Gradle process them in small pieces.
I updated build.gradle, settings.gradle and all dependencies, but @ContextConfiguration can't find main class from another module.
import com.data.server.MainServerApp

@ContextConfiguration(classes = MainServerApp.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties="spring.cloud.config.enabled=false")
class SuperTest extends Specification {
 ... ... ...
}

I run gradle clean :server-test:test and get an error:
SuperTest.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.data.server.MainServerApp
 @ line 3, column 1.
import com.data.server.MainServerApp

Could you please suggest what is wrong?

I found a solution.
Spring context searches for the Main class and application.yml in the current module. If these files are missing in the current module - Spring context searches for them in the other modules and uses first available.
As a result it found another Main class (not a MainServerApp).
To fix this problem it is needed to remove all previous Main files
OR create new Main class for the current module.
